# how to achieve append operation in wso2 esb using file-connectors?

Tags: wso2-esb

I need to append content into existing file using file connectors in wso2esb.
My output_file content should be like (after performing append operation)
[1]
**SNO|FNAME|LNAME|EMAIL|PHONE|ADDRESS|SELLING_DEALER|PHONEVALID|MAILVALID
51|chris|clark|cpark3@hotmail.com|0406755889|Longfellow|MacGregor|valid|valid|**

But i am getting the following as output 
[2]
**SNO|FNAME|LNAME|EMAIL|PHONE|ADDRESS|SELLING_DEALER|PHONEVALID|MAILVALID
51187|chris|clark|cpark3@hotmail.com|0406755889|Longfellow|MacGregor|

valid|valid|**
(here i got valid|valid in next line,not under PHONEVALID|MAILVALID column)

my code snippet for fileconnectors-append operation(PHONEValidation) is

```
**<property name="destination" scope="default" type="STRING" value="E:/Justin/files/Output/Output_File.txt"/>
 <property name="validphone" scope="default" type="STRING" value="valid|"/>
<property name="position" scope="default" type="STRING" value="7"/>
     <fileconnector.append>
                <destination>{$ctx:destination}</destination>
                <inputContent>{$ctx:validphone}</inputContent>
                <position>{$ctx:position}</position> 
    </fileconnector.append>**
```

my code snippet for fileconnectors-append operation(EMAILValidation) is

```
**<property name="destination" scope="default" type="STRING" value="E:/Justin/files/Output/Output_File.txt"/>
   <property name="validemail" scope="default" type="STRING" value="valid|"/>
 <property name="position" scope="default" type="STRING" value="8"/>
  <fileconnector.append>
         <destination>{$ctx:destination}</destination>
         <inputContent>{$ctx:validemail}</inputContent>
         <position>{$ctx:position}</position> 
   </fileconnector.append>**
```

So here i want to know how to give valid position in file connector for getting output_file content  which is mentioned above[1].would anyone please help me?

Awaiting for your response,
Thanking you.

Comment: Try by not passing position, as if you are not passing position then the values will be appended to end of the file

Answer (score 0):

Try below proxy and check , as it is working for me

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="FileConnector_create"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="destination"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"
                   value="D:/Test4.txt"/>
         <property name="validphone"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"
                   value="valid|valid"/>
         <fileconnector.append>
            <destination>{$ctx:destination}</destination>
            <inputContent>{$ctx:validphone}</inputContent>
            <position>{$ctx:position}</position>
         </fileconnector.append>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Hi @amg_amit,
Thanks for your response.I am getting the same response eventhough not giving positon.Next,code which you shared above,is not working for my scenario,because phonevalidation either gives valid or invalid response,not both.same as for email validation also.So not possible to give directly the values like below

<property name="validphone"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"
                   value="valid|valid"/>
My expected_output is 

PHONEVALID|MAILVALID
valid|valid   (if both phone and email validation is correct) or vice versa

Comment: Hi @Justin , as you have not shared entire code so whatever snippet was provided i built based on that, if you want the desired solution then you need to share entire code

Comment: Hi @amg_amit,

I have called service for validation even i don't know the sourcecode of that.it will give some response.So i set that response into properties 
FYI,
[link]**https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-XOhPmRdw8kXkco4lo91bCUNB_DYQW1Lw7bUo7un9_s/edit?usp=sharing**